# real time notifications with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, live

I'm trying to find some php and jquery tutorial/plugin or piece of code which enables to get the real time notifications. For example, if some data is inserted in the database, i want to receive the notification on the webpage in real time without refresh etc. If you know any resource, please let me know. Bundle of thanks.

Comment: http://www.ape-project.org/demos/ .. it might help u .. I havet use it .. I have seen demos only

Answer (score 1):

You will need to poll the server, preferably using [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) (not trivial with PHP).

The server can respond blank, or a JSON message if there is something to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

here is periodic updater built as a jQuery plugin that tries to implement long polling and reduce the load on the server.

https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater/